# Javascript object method returning as undefined

Tags: javascript, function, object

I've been struggling with this bit of code for quite a few days. Essentially it's an object that takes the input of 3 text boxes and concatenates them into a string.. or that's what it should do.

Student.toString returns as undefined or "Uncaught TypeError: Property 'Student' of object [object Object] is not a function" when it should be last name, first name and then id number. Can anybody explain what I did wrong on this?

```
    <div id='textInside'>
    First Name:<input type='text' id='fName'><br>
    Last Name:<input type='text' id='lName'><br>
    Student Id: <input type='text' id='stuId'><br>
    <button onclick='readInputs()'>Update</button>

    <p id='stuInfo'></p>
</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    var fiName = document.getElementById('fName');
    var laName = document.getElementById('lName');
    var studeId = document.getElementById('stuId');
    var toP = document.getElementById('stuInfo');

    var Student = new Object;

    function Student() {
        this.firstName = fiName;
        this.lastName = laName;
        this.studentId = studeId;
        this.toString = function() {var result = toP.innerHTML = this.lastName + this.firstName + this.studentId};
            return result;
        this.readInputs = function() { };
    }



    function readInputs() {
        Student();
        Student.toString();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: next time, put your example in a JSfiddle and you'll make us all that much happier.  http://jsfiddle.net/YnqxC/

Comment: You have two `Student`. And you didn't use `new`, trouble. And your `toString` requires an instance.

Comment: There are several issues with the code you've posted. It might be best to clarify what you want to do.

Comment: @DanFarrell—no, it won't. Posting concise code here is to be preferred as it is more convenient and keeps the code associated with the question rather than abstracted to some other site.

Comment: The two aren't mutually exclusive.

Comment: Maybe the following answer can help you understanding prototype and constructor functions: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941 It may be a lot to take in but it's worth it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is… a lot wrong here.

```
var Student = new Object;

function Student() {
    this.firstName = fiName;
    this.lastName = laName;
    this.studentId = studeId;
    this.toString = function() {var result = toP.innerHTML = this.lastName + this.firstName + this.studentId};
        return result;
    this.readInputs = function() { };
}
```

First off, use `{}`, not `new Object`. Next, this will just set `Student` to a `new Object` and overwrite your function, since the function is hoisted. I’m pretty sure you just meant to have the one function there.

Next, `return result;` isn’t inside your `toString` function, which is an error, and again not the one you’re reporting. Is this actually your code? Use the prototype, too. And `toString` shouldn’t have side-effects and constructors shouldn’t read globals.

```
function Student(firstName, lastName, studentId) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.studentId = studentId;
}

Student.prototype.readInputs = function() {};

Student.prototype.toString = function() {
    return this.lastName + this.firstName + this.studentId;
};
```

Now `readInputs` can look like this (does it have something to do with the empty function on `Student`s, by the way?):

```
function readInputs() {
    var s = new Student(fiName.value, laName.value, studeId.value);
    toP.innerHTML = s.toString();
}
```

Note that you have to use `new` with constructors to create `this` properly, and grab the `value` property of input elements, and actually do something with the return value of the function.

This error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Property 'Student' of object [object Object] is not a function

seems impossible to me, but I could just be missing something. (Are you on IE8?)

Comment: Nice answer. The error is because of the hoisting, you mentioned it. A `new Object` is not a function, in `Student()`.

Comment: @elclanrs: Yep, I was just wondering where the “of [object Object]” is coming from. Some version of some browser, I guess.

Comment: I see, yeah I'll go for IE, blaming on IE seems right.

Comment: @elclanrs—blame IE for what? The error is returning the `[[Class]]` of the object in much the same way *typeof* does and is saying "this object is class Object and doesn't implement call, therefore it isn't a function". I am no fanboi for IE, but there is no reason to bash it here.

Comment: @RobG: No, I just mean that the right error seems like it would be “TypeError: Student is not a function” or “TypeError: object is not a function”. It’s a variable, and it doesn’t really look like a property of `window` (which I’m assuming is how this error is treating it). Plus `[object Window]` would be useful there.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this

```
 var student = new Student(fiName,laName,studeId);
 var res = student.toString();

 function Student(fiName,laName,studeId) {
        this.firstName = fiName;
        this.lastName = laName;
        this.studentId = studeId;
    }

   Student.prototype.toString = function() {
        return this.lastName + this.firstName + this.studentId
    }
```

Above is an example of object oriented java script code. I have defined a Student constructor function and defined a toString method on the new Student type.
It's recommended to add your methods to the prototype chain in order to tie them to the type and not just a particular instance.

Comment: Please include an explanation, don't just post code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id='textInside'>
First Name:<input type='text' id='fName'><br>
Last Name:<input type='text' id='lName'><br>
Student Id: <input type='text' id='stuId'><br>
<button onclick='readInputs()'>Update</button>

<p id='stuInfo'></p>
</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    var fiName = document.getElementById('fName');
    var laName = document.getElementById('lName');
    var studeId = document.getElementById('stuId');
    // Where is <node id="stuInfo" /> defined?..
    var toP = document.getElementById('stuInfo');

    function Student() {
        this.firstName = fiName.value;
        this.lastName = laName.value;
        this.studentId = studeId.value;
        this.toString = function() {
            var result = toP.innerHTML + this.lastName 
                + this.firstName + this.studentId
            return result;
            };
    }

    function readInputs() {
        var a_student = new Student();
        alert(a_student.toString());
    }
</script>
```

Comment: it's for the sample, doesn't know what he's script does

Comment: *// Where is <node id="stuInfo" /> defined?..* It’s right up there: `<p id='stuInfo'></p>`

Answer (score 0):

You should put .value after you get the elements id. Because you can get the id of an element but not its value.

```
var fiName = document.getElementById('fName').value;
```

so that's makes your variable have a value.

Answer (score -3):

To instanciate on object you have to use the word new

Since you generate student, you have to give as argument to the constructor

The code should looke like this

```
<div id='textInside'>
    First Name:<input type='text' id='fName'><br>
    Last Name:<input type='text' id='lName'><br>
    Student Id: <input type='text' id='stuId'><br>
    <button onclick='readInputs()'>Update</button>

    <p id='stuInfo'></p>
</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
var Student = function( option ) {
    this.firstName = option.fiName;
    this.lastName = option.laName;
    this.studentId = option.studeId;
    this.top = option.top;
};

Student.prototype.toString = function(){
     return document.write(this.lastName +" "+ this.fastName +" "+ this.studentId);
};

function readInputs() {
    var student = new Student({
         fiName: document.getElementById('fName').value.trim(),
         laName: document.getElementById('lName').value.trim(),
         studeId: document.getElementById('stuId').value.trim(),
         top: document.getElementById('stuInfo').value.trim()
    });
    student.toString();
}
</script>
```

Comment: This is a good start, but it would be nice if you described your answer and removed the `var fiName = ;`s.

Comment: Yeah i was editing the code, did you vote down for that?

Comment: I am not going to answer that. Anyways, you *can* finish your answer before posting it…